# How to make part of a plot dotted

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Suppose that we have the following dataframe.

```
d = {'quarter':['2018-1', '2018-2', '2018-3', '2018-4', '2019-1'], 'number':[131, 157, 136, 155, 263]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Now I would like to plot this, which I did using

```
ax = plt.gca()
df.plot(x='quarter', y='number', ax=ax, label='Data')
plt.xticks(df.index, df['quarter'].values)
```

Now the thing is, I would like the line from on the x = 2018-4 to the x = 2019-1 to be dotted, since this is a prediction.

**My question**
How can I make part of the plot dotted?

Comment: Did my solution help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possibilty to do this without digging deep into the Line2D artist (if even possible), is to plot two different lines:

```
ax = plt.gca()
df.iloc[:-1].plot(ax=ax, label='Data', color='C0')
df.iloc[-2:].plot(ax=ax, label='Data', color='C0', ls=':')
plt.xticks(df.index, df['quarter'].values)
ax.legend(['Data', 'Prediction'])
```

There are a few things I'd recommend to change for easier processing of the data:

- Make timestamps out of the quarter-data
- Make a separate column for data and prediction, setting all unavailable values in each column to `np.nan`

Answer (score 1):

Plot them seperately by calling plot twice; Just slice your Array

```
plt.plot(x[:2018-4] + x[2019-1:], y[:2018-4] + y[2019-1:])
plt.plot(x[2018-4:2019-1], y[2018-4:2019-1])
```

There's also a keyword argument to make sure they both have the same color; iirc it's just `color=`blue` for example

Comment: Slicing an array with `x[:2018-04]` etc. won't work (at least not in the way you want it to work in this case...). `2018-4` will be interpreted as the integer index `2014`.

Comment: @Scotty1- Just now noticed that his x= wasn't actually his x indices. Well then he'll has to Change so that his indices are correct, Basic concept is the same

Comment: Nope, have you tried `df[:2018-4]` or `df.values[:2018-4]`? This is equivalent to `df[:2014]` which will return **ALL** values until the 2014th element of the array, **if `df.shape[0] >= 2014`, **else** all values until the end of df. This is exactly what he **doesn't want**.